# What happened to players with the Waffentrager E100 after the removal update?

Tags: world-of-tanks

As the question suggests.

It got me thinking, since the Waffentrager E100 got replaced by the Grille 15. Does that mean that players with the Waffle get the Grille in its place? Or do they get their silver back as compensation? Or does the Waffle become a premium tank for those players?

Comment: The only ones who could probably answer this is WG, and they will often post something about it when there are tech tree changes.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this removal happened about two years ago.  This should be answerable.

Comment: Well then I guess I've been living under a rock since then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Waffle is gone forever, and the grille simply takes its place with everything (XP, crews, etc) transferred.

Grille is still a nice tank. Pretty fast with a great gun.

Comment: Seriously? Just like that? So players who had the waffle automatically got the grille?

Comment: @GipsyD yup. It's as simple as you think it is. just swap one tank out and replace the other. everything else is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is just replaced by the Grille 15, just like what registered user said.

Grille has one of the best guns (accuracy wise) and can keep up with most "hovercraft" mediums

fyi : WG has a track record of replacing the old tanks with new ones for balancing reasons and players just get all their XPs, crews and so on transferred

Examples:

i.)  replacement of t30 by t110e5 as the tier 10 heavy tank

ii.) replacement of fv4202 by the Centurion Action X  tier 10 medium

for the t30, players who own it gets the t110e5 for free and a complimentary t30 tier 9 TD as well. As for the Action X, players who own the fv4202 gets the new tank for free while the fv4202 gets dropped down to being a tier 8 premium. Dont really remember whether they get the FV for free or they have to grind it in a marathon mission.

Answer (score 0):

Players who haved it have now Grille 15, it has been replaced :)